# Missing method definition AudioSource.Play() in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move an object using an Audioclip in unity.When I compile my script i get 
'AudioSource' does not contain a definition for 'Play' and no extention method'Play' accepting a first argument of type 'AudioSource' could be found.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question with the code you are using. Also, you might want to read [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you're storing a reference to your Audio Source. Assuming the Audio Source is on the same Game Object as the script:

```
private AudioSource audioSource;

void Start () {
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        audioSource.Play ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To whoever encounters this problem in the future, I found the answer in this post below. It only happens when you name your script AudioSource which ends up conflicting with Unity's AudioSource. Changing the script name should allow the AudioSource.Play() to work

['AudioSource' does not contain a definition for 'PlayOneShot' in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034732/audiosource-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-playoneshot-in-unity)